# How to use recursion in JavaScript for try do function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to make this code prettier with recursion.

```
findModel = function(oldModel, ...modelStyles) {
    let model = oldModel.elements;
    let i = 0;
    try {
        do {
            model = model.children.find(child => child.mStyle === modelStyles[i]);
            i += 1;
        } while (i < modelStyles.length);
        return model;
    } catch (e) {
        return undefined;
    }
};
```

tried this:

```
findModel = function(oldModel, ...modelStyles) {
    let model = oldModel.elements;
    let i = 0;

    if (i < modelStyles.length) {
        model = model.children.find(child => child.mStyle === modelStyles[i]);
        i += 1;
        return model;
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
};
```

but it's still not working well. in the first code I get only the element, in the second one I get also undefined.

What did I wrong?

Comment: Hi mate, that's not recursive...

Comment: You are never calling the function inside itself in the second example. It's not yet recursive.

Comment: @Nicolas I defined the model and i now in the second example. But still same.

Comment: @trincot i was not defined, if the modelStyles.length is 5 > i Expect 5?

Comment: this is not even recursive you are not even calling the function again.

Comment: @SaifAli, welcome to the club...

Comment: @SaifAli Can anyone help instead of placing the same comment :) ?

Comment: No one can write code for someone if they don't even know the basics of something try improving your knowledge of what recursion is and then show us what you have tried. We will be happy to help.

Comment: Note there isn't such a thing as a "try do" here. The try/catch is not needed in the first section of code. If this is just about making the code cleaner, then recursion is not needed for this. It can just be a normal for loop.

Comment: BTW, you cannot use this function recursively just-like-that, because in the recursive call your `model` would not have an `elements` property. You would need to use a different function to take a `model` that has a `children` property, not `elements`, or agree that you will make the initial call to `findModel` passing the `elements` property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As amply noted in comments, you are actually never calling the function recursively.

When it comes to "pretty", I would not go for recursion, but for `reduce`:

```
var findModel = function(oldModel, ...modelStyles) {
    try {
        return modelStyles.reduce((model, style) => model.children.find(child => child.mStyle === style), oldModel.elements);
    } catch (e) {} // No need to explicitly return undefined. It is the default
};
```

If you really need recursion, then first realise that your function expects a first argument type that never occurs again. Only the toplevel model has an `elements` property, so you can only call this function for ... the top level of your hierarchy.

To make it work, you would need another function that takes the `model` type as it occurs in the `children`:

```
var findModel = function(oldModel, ...modelStyles) {
    function recur(model, style, ...modelStyles) {
        if (style === undefined) return model;
        return recur(model.children.find(child => child.mStyle === style), ...modelStyles);
    }
    // Need to change the type of the first argument:
    try {
        return recur(oldModel.elements, ...modelStyles);
    } catch (e) {}
};
```

If you would change the code where the function is *called initially*, you could of course pass `mainmodel.elements` instead of `mainmodel`, so that this type difference problem is resolved. If you can make that change, then the recursive function can become:

```
var findModel = function(model, style, ...modelStyles) {
    if (style === undefined) return model;
    try {
        return recur(model.children.find(child => child.mStyle === style), ...modelStyles);
    } catch (e) {}
};
```

Still, I would prefer the `reduce` variant.

Comment: It's not working, you didn't define the model. I added but still not working as expected.

Comment: *"you didn't define the model"*. How could I? I thought you had the model already and your original code was working. Making the model was not part of your question. If the model is the problem, could you please edit your question and show what model you have? Here is `reduce` working on some sample data I invented: https://jsfiddle.net/cjah7o4L/ It returns the correct object.

Comment: So did you see how it worked? If you still have a problem, I am happy to look at it if you can provide a fiddle for it.

Comment: is it possible to use the reduce version without try catch?
removed the try catch, it works with return only but not when the value is undefined, tried to add | undefined to the return line but that didn't work.

Comment: You could replace `model.children.find` with `model && model.children.find`, or (if it is not guaranteed that the `children` property exists) `model && model.children && model.children.find`

Answer (score 0):

The point of recursive function is to call themselves into themselves. In your case, you are calling the function once, but the function never call itself so it just go through once. I'm not sure of the context so I can't fix your code but i can give you an example of recursion.

Lets say we have an object with property. Some are string, some are number and some are objects. If you want to retrieve each key of this object you would need recursion, since you don't know how deep the object goes.

```js
let objectToParse = {
  id: 10,
  title: 'test',
  parent: {
     id: 5,
     title: 'parent',
     someKey: 3,
     parent: {
         id: 1,
         title: 'grand-parent',
         parent: null,
         someOtherkey: 43
     }
  }
};

function parseParentKey(object) {
  let returnedKey = [];
  let ObjectKeys = Object.keys(object);
  for(let i = 0; i < ObjectKeys.length; i++) {
     if(typeof object[ObjectKeys[i]] === "object" && object[ObjectKeys[i]] !== null) {
      // we are calling the methode inside itself because
      //the current property is an object.
      returnedKey = returnedKey.concat(parseParentKey(object[ObjectKeys[i]]));
     }
     returnedKey.push(ObjectKeys[i]);
  }
  return returnedKey;
}

console.log(parseParentKey(objectToParse));
```

I know this does not answer your question but it gives you a hint on how to use recursion properly. If your first code works, I don't see why you would need to change it in the first place.